# C++ Are there any tutorials on how to use handles?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, handle

I'm trying to create an application that makes extensive use of the `HANDLE`.  I've done many searches for tutorials on these, but have found none.  Are there any tutorials out there on how to create a `HANDLE`?

NOTE: I would like a tutorial on how to create a `HANDLE` complete with `Create`, `Get`, and `Delete` functions.

Comment: "Handle" is a pretty vague concept. Handle to what?

Comment: Are you referring to something like the `HANDLE` type in the Windows API that can represent a handle to a file, handle to a thread, or many other things?

Comment: @chris: Yes I am.  I didn't think that the word "handle" was that vague in C++.

Comment: @TimothyChapman, Well, it's an extremely broad question then. The single `HANDLE` type can be for a lot of different things (threads, files, processes, mutexes...). Each one is used differently, so discussion would be very widespread. For example, you can get one to a file with `CreateFile` or one to a process with `OpenProcess`. As well, there are other types such as `HWND` for windows, `HDC` for device contexts, and a bunch more of those also. It's sort of like asking how to use a resource. Which resource? Each one is used differently.

Comment: @chris: Oh. I want to know how to **create** a `HANDLE`. I will clarify my post.

Comment: @TimothyChapman, I'd say that's much better than before, but do note the reason for the closing. As shown in the answer, it's possible to make a simple one without a lot of code. Asking for an off-site tutorial is the low point.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a handle is just something you give to users to represent some data that you have internally, to prevent them from fooling around with it.  One easy way to do this is simply using a pointer.

Public Header:

```
struct my_private_data;
typedef my_private_data* MPDHANDLE;

MPDHANDLE get_new_object();
void do_task(MPDHANDLE hnd);
void release(MPDHANDLE hnd);
```

And that's what you give to people.  They don't know anything whatsoever about my_private_data, so the compiler will make it hard for them to do anything wrong with it.  And theres no other functions that accepts a MPDHANDLE, so it's hard for them to screw it up.

Internally, your library has this code:

```
struct my_private_data {
    void do_task();
};
MPDHANDLE get_new_object() {return new my_private_data();}
void do_task(MPDHANDLE hnd) {hnd->do_task();}
void release(MPDHANDLE hnd) {delete hnd;}
```

Which is pretty straightforward.